# Obtener un valor de dataframe. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe con la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y querría obtener el valor para una columna en concreto. Para ello empleo `.loc` pero me equivoco. ¿Me podeis ayudar por favor?

```
import pandas as pd    
data = pd.read_csv('data/marcas.csv')
marcas = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(marcas.loc[1, 'pull ups'])
```

Si hago un `print` a marcas me sale bien pero si quiero ver una columna concreta me falla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu caso no te está funcionando porque has puesto un 1, por lo que eso te devolvería la segunda fila después de los encabezados, y al haber solo una fila, falla. Poniendo un 0 te debería salir bien:

```
print(marcas.loc[0, 'pull ups'])
```

Si lo que quieres es ver la columna entera, puedes probar así:

```
print(marcas['pull ups'])
```

Y otra manera si quieres acceder a una fila en concreto de esa columnapodría ser así:

```
print(marcas['pull ups'][0])
```

Igual que en tu caso, al haber puesto [0] te daría la primera fila, poniendo [1] devolvería la segunda, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Para ver una columna en pandas tiene que poner el nombre del dataframe y entre corchetes el nombre de la columna, en tu caso sería así:

```
marcas['A'] #vemos la columna A
```

- **loc** sirve para ver el valor de una fila por su indice y sería así:

```
marcas.loc[1] #vemos la primera fila
```

- Se pueden usar las dos operaciones a la vez para buscar una columna concreta dentro de una fila (creo que es tu caso)

```
marcas.loc[1]['B'] #obtenemos de la fila 1 la columna B
```

- También puedes elegir una fila y seleccionar varias columnas, esta vez al ser un dataframe necesitarás doble corchete:

```
marcas.loc[1][['B', 'D']] #obtenemos para la fila 1 los valores de las columnas B y D
```

- Incluso puedes seleccionar varias mediante una técnica que se conoce como "slicing":

```
marcas.loc[3:7]['B'] #obtenemos para las filas desde la 3 a la 7, la columna B
```

Como puedes ver Python y Pandas nos ofrecen multiples y diferentes maneras de acceder a los datos de una DataFrame de forma rápida y sencilla (aquí solo te he dejado algunas), hay decenas de técnicas de slicing e indexing, es un mundo.

Comment: Lo único que no śe si tú columna es "pull ups", "muscle ups", etc. O por el contrario la A, B, C, D.